# Trying to create a vector of inner classes with same outer class object

Tags: c++, class

Can't we create an inner class vector as a member of outer class and have a single object of the outer class to push many instances of inner class objects into that vector?.

```
class Outer{
    class Inner{
    };
vector<Inner> innerList;
};
```

Now my requirement is to create a single object for `Outer` and I want to push many `Inner` objects into the vector `innerList`. My problem here is an `Inner` class object can be created only when `Outer` class is created. So whenever i want to create an `Inner` class object there will be an `Outer` class object associated with it. But I want a single `Outer` class object common for a set of `Inner` objects. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Create an instance of `Outer`, and have it create many instances of `Inner`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Is this are you trying to achive:

```
#include <vector>

class Outer{
public:
    class Inner{
    };
    std::vector<Inner> innerList;
};

int main()
{
    Outer object;

    object.innerList.push_back(Outer::Inner());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use some other feature for c++ to achieve your purpose: a "outer" associated with a "inner".
for example, you can use "map" lisk this:

```
class Outer{
};
class Inner{
};

map <Outer, vector<Inner>> &;
```

hope this will help.